# PHP variable not echoing on page via ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having a problem with my code as my php variable is not being echoed on page when using ajax jquery. Here is my code...

```
<script>
    function refresh_div() {
     $('.loader').show();
     var username = "<?php echo $user; ?>";
     jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "load.php",
            data:{user : username},
            success:function() {
                jQuery("#load_msgs").append(response+'<br>');

            },
            complete: function(){
        $('.loader').hide();
      }
        });
    }

    t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);
</script>
```

i am trying to send "username" to page url "load.php"... i called it this way but nothing is being echoed...

```
if(isset($_POST['user'])) {
     echo $_POST['user'];
}
```

pls help out thanks... :)

edited...

when i tried using this code i.e adding passing response as parameter in success function like this ...

```
<script>
    function refresh_div() {
     $('.loader').show();
     var username = "<?php echo $user; ?>";
     jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "load.php",
            data:{user : username},
            success:function() {
                jQuery("#load_msgs").append(response+'<br>');

            },
            complete: function(){
        $('.loader').hide();
      }
        });
    }

    t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);
</script>
```

.... the data (username) gets displayed every second.. like a blink toggling on and off the page... how do i make the data display static in order to use the variable on the ajax page. Thanks :)

Comment: Check the request headers & from data on network tab.

Comment: change `success:function() {` to `success:function(response) {` also you did not specify dataType so you need to parse

Comment: when i changed it to success:function(response) { , it kept toggling on and off very frequently(every second probably)... i already tried that

Comment: can you add dataType:text and try

Comment: where did you wrote your JS code ? in same PHP file ? if code is written in php file, then it should echo the var.

Comment: my js code is in the same php file but it is not being echoed and i can't figure out why... "chat.php",..... the page being called is "load.php"... that is where i need the variable to be echoed thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where the `response` variable you get? Should be :

```
success : function( response ) {
   jQuery("#load_msgs").append(response+'<br>');

},
```

Comment: i did this and it started echoing data and disappearing every second.. like a blink... what can i do to stop the toggling?

Comment: Does the data append inside `#load_msgs` container?

Comment: yes... then it starts toggling off and on.. every second

Comment: What is `$('.loader')`?

Comment: loader is the class of the spinning img gif i used

Answer (score 0):

please take a datatype as json in ajax call
and in loads.php function add two line as below..

```
if(isset($_POST['user'])) {
     $data['user'] =  $_POST['user'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

also change in success function.

```
success:function(response) {
                jQuery("#load_msgs").append(response.user);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more simplified would be:

```
$.post(URL, { data: somefield }, function(result) {
    result = JSON.parse(result);
    If(result && result.status === 'true'){

    }
)};
```

Depends a bit on the return at server side.

Answer (score 0):

You missed response in success function.
Try this:

```
<script>
    function refresh_div() {
     $('.loader').show();
     var username = "<?php echo $user; ?>";
     jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "load.php",
            data:{user : username},
            success:function(response) {
                $("#load_msgs").append(response+'<br>');

            },
            complete: function(){
        $('.loader').hide();
      }
        });
    }

    t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);
</script>
```