# php variable not being echoed via ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I am having a problem with my code as my php variable is not being echoed on page when using ajax jquery. Here is my code...

```
<script>
    function refresh_div() {
     $('.loader').show();
     var username = "<?php echo $user; ?>";
     jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "load.php",
            data:{user : username},
            success:function() {
                jQuery("#load_msgs").append(response+'<br>');

            },
            complete: function(){
        $('.loader').hide();
      }
        });
    }

    t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);
</script>
```

i am trying to send "username" to page url "load.php"... i called it this way but nothing is being echoed...

```
if(isset($_POST['user'])) {
     echo $_POST['user'];
}
```

pls help out thanks... :)

edited...

when i tried using this code i.e adding passing response as parameter in success function like this ...

```
<script>
    function refresh_div(response) {
     $('.loader').show();
     var username = "<?php echo $user; ?>";
     jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "load.php",
            data:{user : username},
            success:function() {
                jQuery("#load_msgs").append(response+'<br>');

            },
            complete: function(){
        $('.loader').hide();
      }
        });
    }

    t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);
</script>
```

.... the data (username) gets displayed every second.. like a blink toggling on and off the page... how do i make the data display static in order to use the variable on the ajax page. Thanks :)

Comment: Just pass response in success function  `success:function(response) {`

Comment: You appear to already have asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014264/php-variable-not-echoing-on-page-via-ajax-jquery. If the solutions provided there did not work, please comment on those answers and edit your question to include more detail.

Comment: @PraveenKumar ?? What? the text in the questions match 100%

Comment: @Epodax Oops... Sorry.

Comment: i did i need an urgent answer that is why i posted another one...all the solutions on the previous post didn't work  @Rory McCrossan

Comment: @adetiwa - SO is not a "Fix my code ASAP".

Comment: @Epodax nobody responded on that one again so i created another... sorry if i broke any rule here..,just created this account 6 hours ago... and yes i want to fix my code ASAP :)

Comment: The 1st comment answers your question. Why havent you tried that? Also the second code block in your question (the bit after `edited...`) is identical to the 1st

Comment: @adetiwa Wait, your edit isn't what all answer mean. Check it again and again...

Comment: @Steve i am sorry that was typographical i just corrected it by adding response into success function.... none worked fine. the first didn't display anything... the 2nd displayed and kept toggling on and off like every second.

Comment: @adetiwa It is toggling BECAUSE you are using an interval... Seriously?!  You should ASAP try to understand code you are obviously copying/pasting from random source

Comment: @adetiwa **REMOVE THE CODE:** `t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);`

Comment: @A. Wolff  i am sorry i didn't get you

Comment: @A. Wolff but when i removed t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000); nothing gets displayed :(

Comment: @Praveen Kumar i tried removing t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000); nothing gets displayed :(

Comment: @adetiwa What about `refresh_div();`?!... Looks like you put so little effort to understand what you copy...

Comment: @adetiwa Replace your `t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);` with `refresh_div()`.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar  hi there i just took out the setinterval() and called the function normally.... it displayed and then went out... like seriously

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining `response` anywhere. Send it as the parameter of the `success` handler:

```
success: function(response) {
    jQuery("#load_msgs").append(response+'<br>');
},
```

Comment: I tried defining response like you suggested before , it displayed but kept toggling on and off every second like a blink.... do you have any idea why it is doing that?

Comment: @adetiwa You aware you are using an interval, right?!...

Comment: @adetiwa It is because you are using `setInterval()`.

Comment: @A. Wolff yes i am... to reload messages every second asynchronously

Comment: @adetiwa For now, please replace your `t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);` with `refresh_div()`.

Comment: @adetiwa Awesome, and then why don't you expect it to 'blink'?!

Comment: @Praveen Kumar hi i just did.... replaced setinterval() and called the function normally... it displayed and and then stoped displaying... no blinking though. just once this time

Comment: @A. Wolff I just did... it just displayed the variable once and then went off... what do i do this time pls?